# Number of iterations a for loop has made

Tags: arrays, c, loops, search, numbers

I'm trying to make a program that looks for a number in an array, says the position of this number, and how many times the for loop has been executed. I'm struggling with the part where I have to count the number of times it needs to find that number. Something like this:

```
int main(){
    
    array[]=5,1,3,6,4,5,7,12,8,9,10;
    int i = 0, number;
    int NumberFound = 0;
    
    printf("Enter the number you are looking for: \n");
    scanf_s("%d", &number);
    for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        if (number == data[i]) {
            NumberFound = 1;   //Number was found
                        
            printf("%d was found in the position %d\n", number, i);
            break;
        }
        else {
            NumberFound = 0;
        }
    }
    
    if (NumberFound == 0) {
        printf("%d was not found \n", number);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I would still like to implement the number of times the for loop has been executed. On the console should be this:

```
Enter the number you are looking for:
3
Iteration 1
Iteration 2
3 was found in the position 2
```

Comment: the number of times the loop has executed is the same as the found index + 1

Comment: @Angie This else statement else {
            NumberFound = 0;
        } does not have an effect and may be removed.:)

Comment: <O/T> no need for `else { NumberFound = 0; }`. `NumberFound` is initialized to 0, and only changes to 1 when the number is found, at which point you break out of the loop.

Comment: @Angie In this declaration array[]=5,1,3,6,4,5,7,12,8,9,10; there is absent  type specifier and braces.

Comment: This line is nonsense, and not at all how C works:
`array[]=5,1,3,6,4,5,7,12,8,9,10;`

Answer (score 0):

Print the value of `i` before breaking the loop as [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) suggested.

```
if (number == data[i]) {
            NumberFound = 1;   //Number was found
                        
            printf("%d was found in the position %d after %d iterations\n", number, I, i+1);
            break;
        }
```

Comment: `i` is the counter.

Comment: Oh my bad! you are  right

Answer (score 0):

The iteration count is `i+1`.

```
    for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        if (number == data[i]) {
            printf("%d was found in the position %d\n", number, i);
            break;
        } else {
            printf("Iteration %d\n", i+1);
        }
    }
```

You don't need to set `NumberFound = 0;` in the `else` block, since it already contains that from the initialization.

Comment: Thank you so much! How can I do so that it appears on the console: Iteration 1 Iteration 2 separetely?

Comment: It should already do that.

Answer (score 0):

For starters there are typos in this declaration

```
array[]=5,1,3,6,4,5,7,12,8,9,10;
```

It seems you mean

```
int array[] = { 5,1,3,6,4,5,7,12,8,9,10 };
```

Also the name `data` used in this statement

```
if (number == data[i]) {
```

is undefined.

This else statement

```
    else {
        NumberFound = 0;
    }
```

does not have an effect and may be removed.

Actually the variable `NumberFound` is redundant. You may remove its declaration and its using

```
int NumberFound = 0;
```

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int array[] = { 5, 1, 3, 6, 4, 5, 7, 12, 8, 9, 10 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( array ) / sizeof( *array );

    int number = 0;
    
    printf( "Enter the number you are looking for: " );
    scanf( "%d", &number );

    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < N && number != array[i] ) 
    {
        printf( "Iteration %zu\n", ++i );
    }

    if ( i == N )
    {
        printf( "%d was not found \n", number );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "%d was found in the position %zu\n", number, i);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is perfect. Thanks a ton !